# Python curses: multiprocessing issue with Pool.map?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ncurses, curses, python-curses

I have an issue with `Pool.map` in combination with the `curses` module of `Python`. Whenever I compute bigger workloads with `Pool.map` my `curses` UI breaks: it does not react upon the default screen's `getch` anymore. Instead of reading in any pressed key instantly (and continuing with parsing it) I can press any amount of keys until I hit enter. Sometimes (in addition to that) even the UI breaks (like showing a fraction of my normal shell).

---

**Curses UI wrapper**

This is a wrapper class (`Screen`) that handles the curses UI stuff for me:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import curses



class Screen(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # create a default screen
        self.__mainscr = curses.initscr()
        self.__stdscr = curses.newwin(curses.LINES - 2, curses.COLS - 2, 1, 1)
        self.__max_height, self.__max_width = self.__stdscr.getmaxyx()

        # start coloring
        curses.start_color()
        curses.use_default_colors()

        # define colors
        curses.init_pair(1, 197, -1)  # red
        curses.init_pair(2, 227, -1)  # yellow
        curses.init_pair(3, curses.COLOR_MAGENTA, -1)
        curses.init_pair(4, curses.COLOR_GREEN, -1)  # darkgreen
        curses.init_pair(5, curses.COLOR_BLUE, -1)
        curses.init_pair(6, curses.COLOR_BLACK, curses.COLOR_WHITE)
        curses.init_pair(7, curses.COLOR_WHITE, -1)
        curses.init_pair(8, curses.COLOR_CYAN, -1)
        curses.init_pair(9, 209, -1)  # orange
        curses.init_pair(10, 47, -1)  # green


    def add_str_to_scr(self, add_str: str, colorpair: int = 7):
        self.__stdscr.addstr(str(add_str), curses.color_pair(colorpair))


    def linebreak(self):
        self.__stdscr.addstr("\n")


    def clear_screen(self):
        self.__stdscr.clear()


    def refresh_screen(self):
        self.__stdscr.refresh()


    def wait_for_enter_or_esc(self):
        curses.noecho()
        while True:
            c = self.__stdscr.getch()
            if c == 10 or c == 27:  # 10: Enter, 27: ESC
                break
        curses.echo()


    def get_user_input_chr(self) -> str:
        return chr(self.__stdscr.getch())


    def get_user_input_str(self) -> str:
        return self.__stdscr.getstr().decode(encoding="utf-8")
```

---

**Actual program**

I've written a small example, since the mentioned failure always happen when I combine `Pool.map` within a `curses` UI and have high workload. The code just computes some useless `mult` and `add` stuff on a `numpy` array.

```
import curses
from screen import Screen
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
import numpy as np

s = Screen()           # initializing my Screen wrapper
np.random.seed(1234)   # setting the rng fixed to make results comparable

# worker function to simulate workload
def worker(arr):
    return arr * 2 + 1

s.clear_screen()    # cleans the screen
s.refresh_screen()  # displays current buffer's content

s.add_str_to_scr("Start processing data...")
s.linebreak()
s.linebreak()
s.refresh_screen()

# data to feed worker function with (sliced by rows)
data_arr = np.random.rand(8, int(1e7))   # <-- big array for high workload

with Pool(cpu_count()) as p:
    buffer = p.map(worker, [data_arr[row] for row in np.ndindex(data_arr.shape[0])])

s.add_str_to_scr("...finished processing:")
s.linebreak()
s.linebreak()
s.refresh_screen()
for row in buffer:
    s.add_str_to_scr(row[0:3])
    s.linebreak()
    s.refresh_screen()

# *Here* the program should wait until the user presses *any* key
# and continue INSTANTLY when any key gets pressed.
# However, for big workloads, it does not react to single key presses,
# but wait for any amount of keys pressed until you hit 'Enter'
s.get_user_input_chr()
curses.endwin()
```

---

Now, when I execute the code with a high workload (i.e. crunching an array of shape `(8, int(1e7)` equals 8 rows with 10,000,000 columns) `curse`'s `getch` breaks and I get this behavior:

[image]

As you can see, I can hit `q` (or any other key) as often as I want, but `curse`'s `getch` does not react. I have to press the Enter key to make it recognize the input.

Moreover the first line gets overwritten with my original shell's output for some reason.

This behavior only happens, when the calculation of `Pool.map` roughly needs 1 second or longer.

When I set `data_arr` to a small array like `np.random.rand(8, 100)` everything works like a charm, but as soon as I feed big arrays where the computation takes like >= 1second, this weird bug appears and breaks my `curses` UI.

Any ideas?

Is `Pool.map` not joining the worker processes correctly somehow?

Comment: Have you tried out higher-level interfaces to curses, e.g. blessings? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blessings/
With any luck, this bad behavior is not present there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll try it out. However, I am really wondering why this strange issue happens...has curses some internal loop that can not wait too long for other processes to finish? Looks really strange to me.

Comment: *blessings* has some range of use (and it's not a "higher-level", etc), but doesn't address this question.

Answer (score 1):

The program is doing what you told it to do:

- you're calling `initscr` (and ignoring the fact that curses creates a top-level window),
- then creating a subwindow which covers most of the screen,
- printing several lines on the screen, refreshing the display after each line, and
- finally at the end, waiting for input from the subwindow.

However, your program doesn't call `cbreak`, `raw`, etc., which would let you read an unbuffered (no "Enter" pressed) character.  Also, the program doesn't turn off `echo`. If the load is light, you won't notice, since response is fast.  But under heavy load, e.g., swapping or high memory/CPU usage, it'll still be recovering when it gets to the prompt.  So you notice.

Regarding the screen size, perhaps you meant

```
self.__stdscr = curses.newwin(curses.LINES - 1, curses.COLS - 1, 0, 0)
```

but supposing that you intended to leave "empty" space around the window, you could improve things by doing

```
        self.__mainscr.refresh()
```

immediately after [`initscr`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-initscr) (which would erase the screen).

Comment: thanks for the tip! Indeed, when I use `cbreak` and `noecho`, the main problem is gone. However, `curses` is still breaking the UI by displaying part of my original shell. Any idea for this?

Comment: Your stdscr doesn't cover the whole screen - it begins on the second line of the screen.  Row/column numbers start at zero.

Comment: ...but shouldn't `mainscr` cover the whole terminal? Moreover, this problem only happens with a large `data_arr`. Whenever it is small (thus, the computation time is just milliseconds) the problem doesn't appear.

Comment: Regarding the screen size: I wanted `stdscr` to be centered and have its borders exactly one row respectively column less in size than the original full screen terminal, so that it creates and "empty border".

Comment: But in your refresh, you did not repaint the "empty border", so it's left as-is.  I'd use `script` to capture the actual output and see the details...